# Changing horizontal design on a long scrollable table

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-tables

I have a long table to showcase on my blog which looks really clunky if I try to put together in a single space so I wrote a small CSS to make the table horizontally scrollable, like this:

```
.table-scroll {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden; 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Now the problem is that the horizontal scroll is looking very bad on PCs, like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Normally the way most scrollbar shows up on mobile devices. Can anyone help me out about how can I make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this (for Chrome and Safari) using `-webkit-scrollbar` and `-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`:

```
.table-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 8px;
}
.table-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.7);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ng3fb0gh/1/

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot for your answer, but it doesn't look like how it show up on mobile devices: http://sitesforprofit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/respt2-m.jpg I mean the scroll bar supposed to be within the content, not below it. Not sure if you are getting my point.

Comment: That can be achieved by wrapping the table in a div (see updated fiddle).

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<style type="text/css">
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e1e1e1;
  border: 0px none #ffffff;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active {
  background: #000000;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #666666;
  border: 0px none #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
  background: #666666;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:active {
  background: #333333;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: transparent;
}
</style>
```

This will change every scrollbar, if you want to modify only the scrollbar in your table, you just need to apply the css to yoir .table-scroll class.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply but it is supposed to look like this: http://sitesforprofit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/respt2-m.jpg I run your code on a fiddle and it doesn't look that way.

Comment: This is the closest I got, https://jsfiddle.net/mc90zx81/
the bar in your image seems to be semi-transparent,but I dont appreciate it very well in the picture, if you want to make it semi-transparentcan just change color using rga (just as i did with the other parts of the scrollbar).